# how to have checked rows show on top in turbotable

Tags: primeng-turbotable

I am using a turbotable where first column is checkbox selection.
I need to show the checked rows on top of the table.

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

primeNG documentation https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/selection

they have an example for that, showing the selected rows at the bottom of the table,

all you have to do is changing the position.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use pTemplate = caption and show details inside that:

```
    <p-table #dt [columns]="cols" [value]="cars" [paginator]="true" [rows]="10">
        <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
                <div style="text-align: right">        
                    <ul>
                        <li *ngFor="let car of selectedCars2" style="text-align: left">
                            {{car.vin + ' - ' + car.brand + ' - ' + car.year + ' - ' + car.color}}
                        </li>
                    </ul>    
                </div>
    </ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
...
</ng-template>
```